# want to try but have problem

Tags: system-installation

hello guys i am not very good at english so i have to ask because i didnt get it from text if its possible....the question is i want to try Ubuntu but i wanna have windows also..is it possible to install Ubuntu and then just switch from Ubuntu to win. and from win. to Ubuntu? i have seen something that after installing Ubuntu there will be something wrong with files on win. ......thanks for answer

Answer (score 3):

You can set up your computer to have both Windows and Ubuntu installed. Each will need their own space on the hard drive. Then you just select which operating system you want to run when you start the computer.

Have a look at this help document: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 0):

it's posible, just install first windows, then when your installing ubuntu, there ara a option to select the size for the new ubuntu isntallation, using free size available on windows's partition.

Alternatively, make 3 partitions, 1 for ubuntu(Min. 10GB), 1 for swapp(size = your Ram memory * 2 app), and 1 for windows(win vista or latter , Min 20 gb) then install windows, and after ubuntu.

If you have installing ubuntu, make a partition for windows and after install windows in that partition, after you have to recover grub2 with the same ubuntu's instalaion media(usb or dvd).

Even, the best and less complicated option is installing win first.